# Analytical Expression for a radius in the circle geometry figure shown

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, circles, tangent-line

[image]

I want to find an expression for r in terms of the other parameters mentioned.
This algorithm will then be used inside an microcontroller , to control the existing machinery

Best Regards 
TaimoorAli

Comment: Well, create the angle $\theta$ that is the rest of the circle.  $\theta = 360 - 2r\pi/arc$. And  $a = (r + r2)\sin \theta/2 + (r + r3)\sin \theta/2$.  You can use that.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, the triangle formed by the centres of the three circles has sides $r+r_2$, $r+r_3$ and $a$, with the angle opposite the side $a$ being $\theta = 2 \pi - \text{arc}/r$.  The Law of Cosines gives you an equation

$$ a^2 = (r+r_2)^2 + (r + r_3)^2 - 2 (r+r_2)(r+r_3) \cos(\theta)$$
However, since $\theta$ is a rational function of $r$, there is no way you're going to get a closed-form solution for $r$ as a function of $r_1, r_2, a, \text{arc}$.  You'll need numerical methods.